# How to use serializeArray values in php?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I got the resize from a form.

```
 resize = $('#resize_form').serializeArray();
```

I put the resize in a hidden and send it to a php page.How to get the resize value in php?

```
<input type='hidden' name='name_print' value='resize '>
```

I dump the value in the received php

```
name_print (String): "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]  
,[object Object],[object Object]" (79 characters)
```

I use firebug and it show this

```
 [Object { name="name_print", value="5555"}, Object { name="hem_up", value=""},  
 Object { name="hem_up_double", value="0"}, Object { name="hem_up_size", value="0"},  
 Object { name="waist_catch", value=""}]
```

### How to use the data  in php? convert it to an array?

I use the JOSN.stringify the data like this

```
[{"name":"name_print","value":"1111111111"},{"name":"hem_up","value":""},   
{"name":"hem_up_double","value":"0"},{"name":"hem_up_size","value":"0"},  
{"name":"waist_catch","value":""}]
```

Comment: Then after getting those great answers to work but you're having problems with newlines and the ilk, you can base64 encode/decode it all. :p

Answer (score 1):

You can't put an array into a form field, you have to convert it into a string first. You can put it in JSON format:

```
resize = JSON.stringify($('#resize_form').serializeArray());
```

Then in PHP, you can use `json_decode()`:

```
$resize = json_decode($_POST['name_print']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `serialize()` instead of `serializeArray()`. It creates a string with your form data so you can send it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // in your php code
   $resizedata = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['resize']),true);
   $resizeval = $resizedata['name_print'];
   print_r($resizeval);
```