# json_decode NULL on $_GET

Tags: php

I have a `$("#stateAttr").serializeArray` pass from input submit form to php page in this format

```
[{"name": "data[stateAttr]", "value": "california, 38.8 million, golden state, 163,696 mi square, 2,448 trillion, sacramento"}]
```

on the php page I did `$b = $_GET["data"]["stateAttr"]` and tried to get the "value" of the array by using `var_dump(json_decode($b))` and I got NULL instead

How do I unserialize the array to get the "value"?

**Update**:
I did this on the client side and got the format like above. I just want to get the value of key "value"

```
var stateAttr = $("#stateAttr").serializeArray;
stateInput.setAttribute("value", stateAttr);
stateInput.setAttribute("name", "data[stateAttr]");
```

Comment: what's `$b` ???

Comment: $b = $_GET["data"]["stateAttr"]

Comment: its `name` or `value`, there is no key "data" in there

Comment: Before you can access any of the data in your string, you have to decode it, so however you send it to your php script, you have to show us the code.

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: @tuyenle  what we are asking that how you are passing your json data to php page,show us that code. please paste your full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get the value:

```
$data= json_decode('[{"name": "data[stateAttr]", "value": "california, 38.8 million, golden state, 163,696 mi square, 2,448 trillion, sacramento"}]');
print_r($data[0]->value);
```

Comment: thanks. I found similar question to mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783819/how-to-use-serializearray-values-in-php